# Como condicionar un string en javascript dependiendo de una variable?

Tags: javascript

el problema es que necesito construir un html, pero tengo una variable llamada "status" y basicamente trae el contacto de una persona, si la variable es true, imprime la tarjeta. Si status en false no imprime nada.

Algo así.

```
$(td_result).html(`
            <a href="mailto:${email}">
                <div class="container-target">
                    <div class="mx-auto">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title mb-0">Details</h5>
                            ${if (status) {`
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                <p class="card-text">Name Example</p>
                                <div class="rounded-circle bg-success ml-2" style="width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <p class="card-text">Hitpath | Aff ID</p>
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                <p class="card-text mb-0">
                                    <span>WhoIs: ${email}</span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            `}`
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        `);
```

Que se les ocurre? Yo se que puedo hacer variables por secciones pero quiero conocer sus formas, quizas haya una buena y sencilla solución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se pueden poner `if ... else ...` dentro de [Plantillas Literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Lo podrías solucionar con [Operadores Ternarios](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Usando tu ejemplo:

```js
$(td_result).html(`
    <a href="mailto:${email}">
        <div class="container-target">
            <div class="mx-auto">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title mb-0">Details</h5>
                    ${status ? `
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <p class="card-text">Name Example</p>
                        <div class="rounded-circle bg-success ml-2" style="width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="card-text">Hitpath | Aff ID</p>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <p class="card-text mb-0">
                            <span>WhoIs: ${email}</span>
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    ` : ''}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>`);
```

Ahora bien, te recomendaría escribir una funcion para aclarar el código.

Te dejo un ejemplo auto-contenido:

```js
var email = "example@email.com";
var status = false;

function ifHasStatusReturnCard(status, email){
    if(status)
        return `
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <p class="card-text">Name Example</p>
                <div class="rounded-circle bg-success ml-2" style="width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
            </div>
            <p class="card-text">Hitpath | Aff ID</p>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <p class="card-text mb-0">
                    <span>WhoIs: ${email}</span>
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </p>
            </div>
            `;
    return '';
}

var str = `
    <a href="mailto:${email}">
        <div class="container-target">
            <div class="mx-auto">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title mb-0">Details</h5>
                    ${ifHasStatusReturnCard(status, email)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>`

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Eres un crack! Realmente ya lo habia resuelto usando variables tal como la funcion, pero no sabia que podia utilizar el operador ternario de esa forma! Y si ese texto lo llevamos a una variable donde el valor dependa tal cual del operador ternario, en el html solo tendremos que imprimir la variable, sea lo que sea.